# undefined method `render' !

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am just creating a simple new action in rails, but when i view it in browser i get this error :

```
undefined method `render' for #<Template:0x9e9993c>
```

the new method is :

```
  def new
    @template = Template.new
  end
```

i have new.html.erb in the folder ! whats the problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a custom object to the `@template` instance variable but `@template` is an internal variable that should hold an instance of the Rails template for the current action.

Use a different variable name

```
def new
  @tpl = Template.new
end
```